# Set Bluetooth Listener on Tizen Wearable

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I'm using `Tizen`'s Wearable SDK to create a watch face, and while I am able to retrieve the Bluetooth's power state by using `blueAdapter = tizen.bluetooth.getDefaultAdapter();` and `bluetoothPowered = blueAdapter.powered;`,  I'd rather use a Bluetooth listener instead of constantly calling `blueAdapter.powered`.

The problem I'm having is that although I did a straight forward copy and paste of the sample code (although I did change the adapter's name, see below) from Tizen's `Bluetooth API` webpage, I'm getting the following error: `'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'blueAdapter.setChangeListener(changeListener)')`.

This is the code I am using:

```
var blueAdapter = tizen.bluetooth.getDefaultAdapter();

var changeListener = {
      onstatechanged: function(powered) {
         console.log ("Power state is changed into: " + powered);
      },
      onnamechanged: function( name) {
          console.log("Name is changed to: " + name);
      },
      onvisibilitychanged: function(visible) {
          console.log("Visibility is changed into: " + visible);
      }
 };

blueAdapter.setChangeListener(changeListener);
```

Not sure if it helps, but I am using the following the `privileges`:

```
http://tizen.org/privilege/bluetooth.admin
http://tizen.org/privilege/bluetooth.gap
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am getting similar kind of error

blueAdapter.setChangeListener is not a function.

Comment: @srkushwaha, just a stab in the dark, but what pivileges do you have? I still haven't figured out my issue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's been a while now, have you tried changing the syntax like below?

```
function changeListener(handler) {
    handler.onstatechanged = function(powered) {
        console.log ("Power state is changed into: " + powered);
        }
    handler.onnamechanged = function(name) {
          console.log("Name is changed to: " + name);
        }
        handler.onvisibilitychanged = function(visible) {
          console.log("Visibility is changed into: " + visible);
        }
};
```

this replaces your listener object by a function, which should then declare the needed functions in the listener. It is just an idea, i did not test it yet.

Comment: Thanks @Nayangar, I have since shelved this project (partly because I upgraded to a newer model of the watch), but I will keep this in mind should I continue with the project (or similar).